Opening .xlsx file in linux terminal
I work in a cluster. I would like to ask if it is possible to open .xlsx files in text editors like nano or vim.
Is there any possible way if I have not Microsoft Excel (or any relevant application in my PC) to read the file.
If it helps my laptop is Windows and I connect via Mobaxterm to the cluster.
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Rocky
Description:    Rocky Linux release 9.4 (Blue Onyx)
Release:        9.4
Codename:       BlueOnyx

You asked "if it is possible to open .xlsx files in text editors like nano or vim" - it's technically possible, but not useful

What would likely elicit useful answers is to explain what you want to achieve (and why using Excel or LibreOffice on your Windows PC client isn't sufficient)

Excel is my PC is sufficient, but I was hoping to open it with a more "terminal procedure". @ChrisDavies

@NasirRiley no I have Excel in my laptop, but I was hoping to open it with a more "terminal procedure".

"I was hoping to open it" - open it to do what? What are you hoping to see?

It is indeed possible to open .xlsx files in vim, nano, or emacs but it isn't viable because those applications aren't designed for working with those files. If you absolutely need top open those files in Rocky Linux, then a better option is to install Libreoffice (libreoffice-calc in particular) and launch it from the command line with libreoffice-calc. Is there some reason that you can't do that?

I didn't say anything about Excel. You can launch libreoffice-calc from a terminal in Rocky Linux after installing it.

xlsx is actually a zip file containing a directory structure of XML documents, describing different aspects of your spreadsheet.
Yes, you can unzip these files into a directory, and access the XML documents as you would like, for example using command line XML tools like xmlstarlet. Of course, XML being a text format, you can open it in your favourite text editor, too. Neovim together with the lemminx XML language server might do quite well as an XML editor, but let's be honest here: these XML files are for machine parsing, not human consumption.
More sensible probably is to write a python program using the openpyxl python module to open the .xlsx file directly and access column data. It's very easy to install that module for you privately without interfering with other people's work.

If you can install a python package, Visidata open a nice ncurses to navigate .xlsx files.
